# 26 flavours of ice-cream, how many different banana splits can be made that have 3 different flavours?

Tags: statistics, permutations, combinations

> A boutique ice cream bar stocks 26 flavours and offers a rainbow
>   banana split that contains 3 scoops of ice cream, each of a different
>   flavour. How many different rainbow splits can the store advertise?

I thought that the answer would just be:
$$^{26}C_3={26 \choose 3}=2600$$
However this is apparently the wrong answer, the only thing I can think of is to view the splits as permutations instead, but surely the order of the scoops doesn't matter?

Comment: How do you know the answer you got is wrong? Can you provide us with the correct answer? Also, the tag "statistics" you added, is probably completely irrelevant to this question

Comment: What is the correct answerr? Do different flavours (vanilla and lemon) have different colours? Does the order of the bows matter?

Comment: It's an online assignment which tells you if your answer is correct or incorrect when inputted. I don't know the answer sorry! :P

Comment: This is all of the information I have been given :(

Comment: Perhaps order matters up to reversal, so CSV is the same as VSC but differs from the other orderings?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was $15600$, obtained using permutaions instead of combinations, incredibly stupid question if you ask me as there was no way of knowing but oh well :(